# How to do an apple script to do an ssh connection?

Tags: variables, ssh, applescript

I'm developing an simple apple script to help on day-a-day ssh connections

Here's a example

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set ServerName to "IP"
    set ServerUserName to "user"
    set ServerPassword to "password"
end tell
```

and now, there's my doubt.

How can I do `ssh username@servername` and also send my password??

It's something like this?

```
do shell script "ssh " & ServerUserName & " @ " & ServerAddress 
dealy 5
keystroke ServerPassword
```

Thanks

Comment: set up public key authentication. Do not hardcode passwords. It is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

While you should not use hardcoded passwords, as mentioned by @Jakuje, you can use this method:

```
tell application "Terminal"
set ServerAddress to "IP"
set ServerUserName to "user"
set ServerPassword to "pw"
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
set currentTab to do script ("ssh " & ServerUserName & "@" & ServerAddress & ";")
delay 5
do script (ServerPassword) in currentTab
end tell
```

Does this help you?